# Angular - pass object from directive to parent scope on click

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm using an angular `directive` to generate a reusable template and show some data in it. The `directive` also has an `ng-click` that should take an object and pass it to the parent `controller`. I'm kind of stuck, not really sure how to pass that data from the `directive` `controller` to the scope of the parent `controller`. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694729/angularjs-pass-object-from-directive-to-controller) but the circumstances are a bit different.

The js code of the directive:

```
angular.module("app")
    .directive('userData', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "directives/userData/userData.html",
        scope: {
            userObj: "="
        },
        controller: function($scope){

        },
        link: function(scope, elements, attrs, controller){

        }
    }
});
```

And this is the `directive` html:

```
<div class="style" ng-click="displayFullDetails(userObj)">{{userObj.first_name}}</div>
```

Parent controller:

```
angular.module("app").controller("parentCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        getDataService.getJsonData().then(function (data) {
            $scope.users = data.data;    
        })

    });

}]);
```

Comment: Can you post your parent controller as well?

Comment: @JeremyWilken just added the parent controller code.

Comment: You could add another scope param onClick: '&' to the child and pass in a function from the parent. Then in the child call the parent function with the object.

Comment: @sledsworth Im not sure I understand.

Comment: Just make the parent a directive as well. It's more modular, and then you can just use your child directives `require` option to require the parent and use it's functionality to give the parent the data.

Look at the section "Directives that communicate" in these docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive